# Compare positive and negative percentages

Tags: percentages, ratio, descriptive-statistics

I know that is a very, very trivial question... But I'd be super thankful for any help.

Lets say you have three values where each describes the velocity of a car.

50 kmh,
100 kmh,
150 kmh

I just want to double check that it is correct to say that:

**50 kmh is 50 % slower than 100 kmh, and 150 kmh is 50 % fast than 100 kmh.**

My doubt is coming from the fact that while 50 kmh is half of 100. 150 is not the double.
Like I said, its probably very trivial...

Comment: It would also be correct to say that $50$ km/h is $50\%$ of $100$ km/h and that $100$ km/h is $200\%$ of $50$ km/h.  If this is still confusing, you can say that $50$ km/h is half  $100$ km/h and that $100$ km/h is double $50$ km/h.